# socat tunnel traffic drops after some time

Tags: linux, networking, udp, tunneling, socat

I have two Linux machines, I want to create a tunnel between them using socat, this is my workaround:

Machine1:

```
socat -d -d UDP-LISTEN:4711,reuseaddr TUN:10.50.50.1/24,iff-up,iff-broadcast,iff-pointopoint
```

Machine2:

```
socat UDP:[M1 public IP]:4711 TUN:10.50.50.2/24,iff-up,iff-broadcast,iff-pointopoint
```

A `tun` device on both machines gets created and their IP addresses get assigned, and after pinging one machine from another, packets get transmitted and everything works fine.

```
PING 10.50.50.1 (10.50.50.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.50.50.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=105 ms
64 bytes from 10.50.50.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 10.50.50.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=99.1 ms
64 bytes from 10.50.50.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=97.7 ms
```

The problem arises when I put some traffic on this tunnel device (using `iperf3` or manually routing some significant traffic through it), after some time, all packets get dropped.
What should I do to be able to use this tunnel for transmitting large data? Is this problem intrinsic to socat tunnels or it's depending on the network infrastructure and ISP (the M2 machine resides in Iran)?

Comment: what does `dmesg` say? what errors are produced when the packets get dropped?

Comment: @Alex No logs appear on ```dmesg``` unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Start both socat processes with options:  -d -d -d -d -lu  and check the messages when transfer starts to fail